# postfix/submission/smtpd[xxxxx]: warning: hostname <**> does not resolve to address <IP>: Name or service not known

Tags: postfix, smtp, fail2ban, smtpd

I installed iRedMail on VPS (Ubuntu). `Fail2Ban` bans my home IP address.

In `/var/log/mail.log` I see messages like:

```
postfix/submission/smtpd[32149]: warning: hostname unallocated.sta.lan.ua does not resolve to address 31.43.102.*: Name or service not known
```

`unallocated.sta.lan.ua` as I understand is the hostname of my home internet provider.

`31.43.102.*` is my home IP.

Where is the problem? Is it Internet Provider problem or my fault where my server\iRedMail is not configured properly (if so, how to fix)?

Comment: That is your "home" IP address? Not the IP address of your VPS?

Comment: @MichaelHampton. Yes, this is not IP of my VPS. IP of my VPS is 88.99.*.*. 31.43.102.* is IP which provider gave me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reverse DNS warning is not really a misconfiguration on your end.  Some ISP's just don't provide [Forward-confirmed reverse DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward-confirmed_reverse_DNS) for their addresses.

I'm assuming that this isn't actually causing mail rejection by Postfix but rather a ban by fail2ban.  You can check your fail2ban configuration for rules that watch `/var/log/mail.log` for a pattern that matches the one you posted and then disable that rule.  Or you can [whitelist](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Whitelist) your home IP address in the fail2ban configuration by adding it to the `ignoreip` list in `jail.conf`.

Comment: You are right, Postfix does not reject mails, but fail2ban bans. I tried to find the rule via `find /etc/fail2ban/ -type f -exec grep -H 'tried different text' {} \;` but no success. It looks like this rule does not exists at all, but in `iptables -L` I see that hostname is rejected. I added hostname to `ipignore`, but it looks like a workaround rather than a right solution.

Comment: @TitanFighter I don't see anything matching this in a default fail2ban installation. Perhaps it is matching some other line in your log.